# how analyzing ethernet signal base on 100Base-TX

Tags: networking, signals, ethernet

I want to analysis Ethernet signal base on 100Base-TX. So I used high frequency oscilloscope in the middle of my Rassbery-pi2 and switch. But Linux send packets all the time and I can not get a clean spectrum of Ethernet signal. I disable network services but it does not work at all. I will be nice if some one helps me how we can get clean spectrum of Ethernet signal base on 100Base-Tx and analyzing it?
I should mention that I can get it in 10 base-T but I have problem with 100Base-TX.

Answer (score -1):

100BASE-TX uses 4b/5b encoding at 125 MBd and MLT-3 modulation. Your oscilloscope needs to be able to pick up 250 MHz.